# skipping first line when writing to csv file

Tags: c#, csv

I have wrote this code to read and write to a CSV file. Is there any way that I could skip writing the first row as its headers and I want to write my own headers to the new file. This is what I have done so far

```
  try 
  {
      using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:/Projects/data/PYAEGON1AEGONRESULT.csv"))
          using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:/Projects/data/PYAEGON1AEGON.csv"))
          {
              heading = "Title, First Name, Surname, Date Of Birth, NI Number,    Gender, Payroll Reference, Address Line 1, Address Line 2, Address Line 3, Address Line 4, AddressLine 5, PostCode, Country, Email, Date Joined Employer, Annual Pensionable Salary, Current Period All Earnings (Monthly), Current Period Pensionable Earnings (Monthly), Emnployee (Amount Deducted), Employer (Amount Deducted), Leaving Date.";
              sw.WriteLine(heading);

              while((txtline = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
              {
                  oldcolumns = Regex.Split(txtline,",");

                  newcolumns[0] = oldcolumns[0];
                  newcolumns[1] = oldcolumns[1];
                  newcolumns[2] = oldcolumns[2]; 
                  newcolumns[3] = oldcolumns[3];
                  newcolumns[4] = oldcolumns[4];
                  newcolumns[5] = oldcolumns[5]; 
                  newcolumns[6] = oldcolumns[6];
                  newcolumns[7] = oldcolumns[7];
                  newcolumns[8] = oldcolumns[9];
                  newcolumns[9] = oldcolumns[10]; 
                  newcolumns[10] = oldcolumns[11];
                  newcolumns[11] = "";
                  newcolumns[12] = oldcolumns[12]; 
                  newcolumns[13] = "United Kingdom";
                  newcolumns[14] = oldcolumns[14];
                  newcolumns[15] = oldcolumns[15];
                  newcolumns[16] = oldcolumns[16];
                  newcolumns[17] = oldcolumns[17];
                  newcolumns[18] = oldcolumns[18];
                  newcolumns[19] = oldcolumns[19];
                  newcolumns[20] = oldcolumns[20];
                  newcolumns[21] = "";

                  csvline = "";
                  for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
                  {
                      csvline = csvline + "\"" + newcolumns[i].Replace("\"","") + "\",";

                  }

                  sw.WriteLine(csvline);
              }
```

Comment: Just add a boolean flag in your code that indicates if it is the first line and don't write if it's true? It's not really clear what you are confused by.

Comment: If you don't want to write the first line use `sr.ReadLine()` once before you start writing.

Comment: Reading and writing csv files are more complicated than that, E.G. what about ',' in the text and other things, you should google csvreader, then all your problems regarding csv are solved automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `sr.ReadLine()` before you actually start reading the input.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:/Projects/data/PYAEGON1AEGONRESULT.csv"))
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:/Projects/data/PYAEGON1AEGON.csv"))
    {
        sr.ReadLine();

        // rest of your code
```

Comment: Tried this. It prints the first line and then skips a line to the third line.. skips a line to fifth line and so on

Comment: I think you put it inside the `while` instead of above it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to write the first line use `sr.ReadLine()` once before you start writing. This advances the reader to the second line.

```
 using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:/Projects/data/PYAEGON1AEGONRESULT.csv"))
 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:/Projects/data/PYAEGON1AEGON.csv"))
 {
     sr.ReadLine();
     // the next ReadLine will read the second line as desired
     heading = "Title, First Name, Surname, Date Of Birth, NI Number,    Gender, Payroll Reference, Address Line 1, Address Line 2, Address Line 3, Address Line 4, AddressLine 5, PostCode, Country, Email, Date Joined Employer, Annual Pensionable Salary, Current Period All Earnings (Monthly), Current Period Pensionable Earnings (Monthly), Emnployee (Amount Deducted), Employer (Amount Deducted), Leaving Date.";
     sw.WriteLine(heading);
     while((txtline = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
         // ...
         sw.WriteLine(csvline);
         // ...
```

Comment: Tried this. It prints the first line and then skips a line to the third line.. skips a line to fifth line and so on..

Comment: @user3734454: maybe you have added the `sr.ReadLine()` into the while-loop. Have a look at my code sample. I only use `ReadLine` once to skip the header before the while-loop.